# Can Cloud APIs be used to fully automate the provisioning of test and development environments in the Cloud?

Tags: scripting, cloud, virtual-machine

My Client is looking to automate the provisioning of their test and development environments in the Cloud.  Their vision is that they will be able to enter in a Web interface information such as the following:

1. Number of servers
2. Number of CPUs
3. RAM
4. Storage
5. Number of Network Ports
6. Backup requirement (if any)
7. OS version
8. Software stack (probably up to middleware)
9. Load balancer

I guess the idea would be to write a script which takes information from here and uses Cloud APIs to provision the environment in the Cloud.  The question is - how much of this could we automate?  The OS version and middleware could be bundled together in a VM image which could then be deployed.  Would a Cloud API allow a VM instance to be set up and then have an image automatically deployed to it?  Would you be able to configure load balancer and firewall settings?

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Yes! (well, see below)

### Long answer

#### APIs for Cloud Servers

Using the APIs from any of the major providers, you can orchestrate deployments that pick and choose the number of servers, CPUs, RAM, storage, OS version, and load balancers. You do have to line up with each provider's base images & flavors though.

Each has their own backup system, depending on the granularity you're looking for.

As for "number of network ports", I haven't seen anything like this. You usually only get one public-facing network, an internal (to a data center) network, and, if you so choose, an isolated network.

#### Image Creation

Pretty much all the providers let you take a snapshot (image) of a currently running server so that you can re-deploy that same image again. You can do this in automation with APIs as well.

#### Deploying Software Stacks

As far as software stack is concerned though, you want to use some configuration management software ([Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/), [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/), [Ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/), [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or even just Fabric scripts) to help you deploy software in automation. Infrastructure as code makes life so much better.

In fact, coming back full circle, with software like [salt-cloud](http://salt-cloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you can layout a map for your infrastructure *as well as* the software to install on each box.

[OpenStack Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat) and [AWS Formation Templates](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/) take this to another level as well for laying out an infrastructure template, even integrating with those same configuration management suites.